# MySQL INSERT --- get the ID (auto_increment) IF one value is UNIQUE

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a better or faster way to return the ID?

The column customer is unique

```
$inserted_id = null;    

if( !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (id,customer) VALUES(null,'foo')" ){  

    // Is it possible to avoid this 2nd query?
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE customer='foo'");

    $inserted_id = $result->fetch_assoc()['id'];

} else {

    $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

}
```

Comment: I don't know of a better or faster way. You'd have to run a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the `id` value from an existing row. You could possibly "hide" some of that in a stored procedure. But that's not necessarily "better" or "faster".

Comment: Vitj, Please check my post.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$last_id = $mysqli->insert_id();` after your insert.  That get's the last generated auto increment.  Your code as it stands will not be accurate.  Updated for Object Oriented perspective.

Comment: This is incorrect. OP is asking for another way to return ID when insertion fails due to duplicate key.

Comment: then he would need `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` at the end of the SQL query for `$result`

Comment: The question could stand to be rephrased with a more clear intent.

Comment: insert_id() is the safest/easiest method to get the insert id. doing a select on the table has much higher overhead than insert_id().

Comment: Updated the question a little. I am struggling with my english skills :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the insert query to `UPDATE` auto incremented column when a duplicate record is attempted to `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO users (id,customer)
VALUES (null,'foo')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

`id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` will return the value of the `AUTOINCREMENT` column for the last `INSERT` and set the value for mysqli_insert_id. This will make last insert id available during all inserts.

Have modified your code:

```
$inserted_id = null;    

if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (id,customer) VALUES(null,'foo') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)" )
{
    $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id; // Will return last insert ID in case of successful inserts as well as failed inserts due to duplicate key
}
```